# SAPUI5 OData binding to table

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I try to bind campaign data from the OData service **CUAN_CAMPAIGN_SRV** to a TableSelectDialog element. In my view I have an Input field with input help:

```
<form:FormElement visible="true">
<form:label>
    <Label text="Campaign" design="Standard" width="100%" required="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit"/>
</form:label>
<form:fields>
    <Input id="campaignId" type="Text" enabled="true" visible="true" width="auto" editable="true" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true" valueHelpRequest="handleValueHelp"/>
</form:fields>
```

The value help calls the function **handleValueHelp** in my controller:

```
handleValueHelp: function(oController) {
     this.inputId = oController.oSource.sId;
     // create value help dialog
     if (!this._valueHelpDialog) {
         this._valueHelpDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
             "my.view.Campaigns",
             this
         );
     this.getView().addDependent(this._valueHelpDialog);
     }

     // open value help dialog
     this._valueHelpDialog.open();
}
```

This is when my **table dialog (fragment)** pops up:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<TableSelectDialog id="campaignSelect" title="Select campaign" items="{path:'/CampaignSet'}" growingThreshold="5">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Name"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="ID"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Created at"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Created by"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <Text text="{CampaignName}"/>
            <Text text="{CampaignId}"/>
            <Text text="{CreatedOn}"/>
            <Text text="{CreatedBy}"/>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</TableSelectDialog>
```

So I tried to bind the EntitySet **CampaignSet** from OData Service CUAN_CAMPAIGN_SRV to the table. Therefore I added this code to my **init() function** of the controller:

```
var uname = "UNAME";
var pw = "PW";

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/CUAN_CAMPAIGN_SRV/",
true, uname, pw);

this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

**The problem is:** the table contains no data and this error shows up in the console:

[image: Developer Console Error Log]

> Translated from german: "In the context of Data Services an unknown internal server error occured"

**iwfnd/error_log says this:**

> Invalid format (return table): Row Number 1, Property Name
>   'ChangedOn', Property Value '0 '

Why does ChangedOn even matter if I don't want to bind this property?

I can call something like below **directly in browser** with success:

https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/CUAN_CAMPAIGN_SRV/CampaignSet('100001625')/CampaignName

What do I do wrong? Thank you for every hint!

---

ChangedOn is set to Nullable in the service definition:

[image: ChangedOn segw]

Comment: Date fields cannot be empty unless the field is sepcificed as "Nullable" on the service definition. Your options are to either change the service, or add some sort of default value to your date. You should look into using the manifest.json file to set the odata services btw.

Comment: UI5 code makes a call as $batch by default. Additionally, if there is an issue with any field, the complete service will throw an error. It does not depend on your binding.

Comment: @Jorg ChangedOn is already specified as Nullable (added screenshot in the description). Furthermore, every campaigns ChangedOn property is set to creation date by default. There does no campaign with ChangedOn value 0/null exist...

Comment: Ok if that's not it, my last observation on your code without running it through a debugger is that the value is actually `'0 '`, which includes a space. I've got nothing else.

Comment: @Jorg Let's assume that there are some "corrupt" data sets. How could I add a default value in this case or do not show these data sets in the table? When this has to be checked so I don't get an application error?

Comment: As @Jorg already mentioned, the empty String is causing the issue. Date parameters needs to be passed as null to the Service (e.g. "ChangedOn": null). You could exclude the corrupt data in the GET using a filter when you read the data. I think it should be $filter=ChangedOn ne null. Instead of adding a default value you could also set it to null which will also fix your Problem.